# How exactly to use `current_app` and `urlconf` arguments of the `reverse()` function in Django

Tags: django, django-views

I had to use the `reverse()` function in my project and i saw usage of the `reverse()` in other projects, but i have never used `current_app` and `urlconf` arguments.

As i read in [docs](http:////https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/urlresolvers/#django.urls.reverse):

> The **current_app** argument allows you to provide a hint to the resolver indicating the application to which the currently executing view belongs. This **current_app** argument is used as a hint to resolve application namespaces into URLs on specific application instances, according to the namespaced URL resolution strategy.
>
> The **urlconf** argument is the URLconf module containing the URL patterns to use for reversing. By default, the root URLconf for the current thread is used.

and the [next](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/urls/#naming-url-patterns) one:

> `reverse('polls:index', current_app=self.request.resolver_match.namespace)`

And if in above code from the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/urls/#naming-url-patterns) `self.request.resolver_match.namespace` results to `author-polls` [instance namespace](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/urls/#term-instance-namespace) why could not i just use `reverse()` without any `current_app` argument like this: 

`reverse('author-polls:index') #no any current_app argument`?

Could you give me some tips or maybe a little usage example, please, to understand how, why and when should i use them properly?